# The issuer certificate does not have a Basic Constraints extension

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, x509certificate2

I am trying to create a certificate using *CertificateRequest* class, and using already created CA certificate as na *issuer*. But I am getting a following exception: **The issuer certificate does not have a Basic Constraints extension.**
The exception is happening on the line:

`X509Certificate2 cert = req.Create(certCA, DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));`

This is my code:

```
public static void CreateCertificate(string username, string password){
           
   var certCA = GetCertificateFromStorage(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, "RootCA");

    RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
    CertificateRequest req = new CertificateRequest("CN=" + username, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);       
    X509Certificate2 cert = req.Create(certCA, DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));

    string path1 = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + username + ".pfx");
    string path2 = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + username + ".cer");

    File.WriteAllBytes(path1, cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password));

    File.WriteAllText(path2,
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
        + Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
        + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
}
```

How can I fix this problem? Even some other suggestion how can I create certificate 'programmatically' would be helpful.

Comment: The obvious question is: does `certCA` have a basic constraints extension?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk when I open CA certificate there is not constraints extension, but I don't know how to fix this.